# Why is this a matrix algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to prove:

> Let $A$ be a finite central simple algebra over a field $k$. Then $[A:k]$ is a square.

proof goes like this:

> The Brauer group of an algebraically closed field is zero, therfore $A\otimes_k k$ is a matrix algebra over $k$. **Q.E.D.**

I am quite puzzled by the fact that the Brauer group of an algebraically closed field being trivial, implies that $A\otimes_k k$ is a matrix algebra over $k$.

**Edit:** It turns out the the paper where I found the proof had a typo. $k$ should have been replaced by $\overline k$. I get it now.

Comment: Dear gebruiker, For many people, the statement that puzzles you would essentially be the *definition* of what it means for the Brauer group to be trivial!  What definition of Brauer group are you working with?  Regards,

Comment: @MattE For $A$ and $B$ csa's we say they are similar if $\text{Mat}(n,A)\cong\text{Mat}(m,B)$ as k-algebras. The Brauer group would then be the equivallence class induced by the *similarity*.

Comment: @gebruiker What are you meaning by this $\cong$? Isomorphism or Morita equivalence? What are $m$ and $n$? Any pair of positive integers? a particular pair? Did you mean to say that $k$ is algebraically closed in the first line since you brought it up later? '

Comment: @rschwieb It doesn't mention what $\cong$ means exactly (I assumed it ment they were isomorphic, but you're making me doubt). $m$ and  $n$ are indeed any pair of positive integers.

Comment: @gebruiker It couldn't be both "isomorphic" and any pair of positive integers. You could make the $k$ dimensions of both sides radically different, and thus make the isomorphism impossible. Could you please go back and clarify that you really have all the information you need to begin?

Comment: @rschwieb My appologies. It actually say that there should **exist** $n,m>0$. Wich is something really different from what I typed....

Comment: Dear @gebruiker : it would also be a good habit to include the subscript on the tensor product. $A\otimes _F k$ could be very different from $A\otimes _k k\cong A$.

Comment: @rschwieb I've made the proper edits...

Comment: @gebruiker Well, $A\otimes_k k\cong A$ as $k$ algebras, so was guessing you did not really want $\otimes_k$, but rather $\otimes_F$ for some field $F\subseteq k$.

Comment: Dear grebuiker, You have several confusions.  For example, $A$ is a central simple algebra, not a field (typically), and so it doesn't really make sense to ask if it is algebraically closed (as you do in your edit).  Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I am quite puzzled by the fact that the Brauer group of an algebraically closed field being trivial, implies that A⊗k is a matrix algebra over k.*

I'm not familiar with your particular version of the definition of the Brauer equivalence relation, but the Artin-Wedderburn theorem says that any finite dimensional simple algebra over an algebraically closed field is a matrix ring over that field. In particular, all of them are equivalent to $k$, even by the definition you gave (since $M_n(k)\cong M_1(A)$ for each finite simple $k$ algebra $A$ for some $n$.)

In your case, you are presumably talking about $A\otimes_F k$ for some field $F\subseteq k$ where $A$ is a finite simple $F$ algebra. Essentially, tensoring with $k$ makes this into a central simple $k$ algebra. At that point, your assumption that the Brauer group is trivial says "this is a matrix ring over $k$."